# Using template tags in external JS file

Tags: wp-localize-script

I’d like to know how to use the `get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' )` tag in an external JS file.

I just found out that it’s possible using the `wp_localize_script` function but I didn’t manage to get it to work …

*functions.php*

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js' );
wp_localize_script('custom_js', 'wp_urls', array( 'template_dir' => get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) ));
```

*header.php* 
(beneath `wp_head();`)

```
<script>
    alert(wp_urls.template_dir);
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe changing to `'wp_urls'` might work?

Comment: I changed every hyphen to an underscore—but it still doesn’t work.

Comment: Is the .js referenced by 'custom_js' loading in the <head>?

Comment: ... and is it loading in the `<head>` ***before*** the `alert`?

Comment: `wp-head();` is called before the `alert` but there’s nothing added in the header by `wp-head();`.

Comment: what [action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) are you using to enqueue and localize your script? you should be using [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)

Comment: I manage to get it to work with `wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/js/google-map.js' );
wp_localize_script('custom_js', 'wp_urls', array( 'template_dir' => get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) ));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you haven't enqueued your script properly. If the script isn't printed, neither are the variables set by `wp_localize_script`. Please read a WP Codex [entry on `wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function. You have to include a path to the script after the handle.

Comment: Yep, I manage to get it to work with `wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/js/google-map.js' ); wp_localize_script('custom_js', 'wp_urls', array( 'template_dir' => get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) ));`